# Angular Bootstrap Collapse Navbar Not Responsive on Mobile Viewports

Tags: responsive-design, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm developing a MEAN application that needs to look good on mobile browsers. At first I was trying and failing to use Bootstrap to make this responsive, as I didn't realize Angular was clashing on the Bootstrap and JQuery JS libraries that Bootstrap depended on.

So I found Angular-UI project on GitHub...sorry for no link but I don't have enough reputation.

I'm trying to get the Collapse Navbar to be responsive on a mobile device. (responsive meaning it adjusts to the "hamburger menu" and the names of the links no longer appear in the menu)

I'm failing to get this to work within the bounds of my Node application.

To isolate the issue, I took the HTML and JS from the plunker referenced by the Angular-UI Bootstrap example (which, by the way also appears responsive to small displays when viewed from a iPhone or Samsung Edge) and made a stripped down Node app, which basically returns what is in the Plnkr example, but that still doesn't appear responsive when viewed from a mobile phone browser (I tested mobile Chrome, Safari, and Firefox)

See screenshot of sample app on OpenShift cloud:

http://angbootstrapnotresponsive-215api.rhcloud.com/assets/

[This sample is not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzGm2.png)

Note: If I view my sample in "responsive" mode in the dev tools, or simply resize my desktop browser window, the menu links fold up into that hamburger menu as desired. Only when I try to use the mobile browser from either iPhone 6 or Samsung Edge this responsive Navbar isn't responsive.

thanks in advance for any ideas!